# Bash - How to replace strings started from the second column and second row of a file?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a `csv` file like this

```
time        my_account  form_token          address         City
13:19:43    username1   aa57d1cd3d5d8845    Street name 1   City 1
13:19:43    username2   aa57d1cd3d5d8846    Street name 2   City 2
13:19:43    username3   aa57d1cd3d5d8847    Street name 3   City 3
13:19:43    username4   aa57d1cd3d5d8848    Street name 4   City 4
```

and I want to replace the values below `my_account` and `form_token` only, so the rest of the columns should be the same without getting replaced. The end result should be like this:

```
time        my_account  form_token      address         City
13:19:43    OhYeah12345 xxxaaaasssss1   Street name 1   City 1
13:19:43    OhYeah12346 xxxaaaasssss2   Street name 2   City 2
13:19:43    OhYeah12347 xxxaaaasssss3   Street name 3   City 3
13:19:43    OhYeah12348 xxxaaaasssss4   Street name 4   City 4
```

Here's the file if you wanna download https://www.dropbox.com/s/t9damejyrlccyam/demo.csv?dl=0

How do I do this with bash ?
Here's what I have done:

```
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '$1 {$3="Another Street"; print}' /tmp/demo.csv
```

But this command also replaces `address` on the first row, I want it to start from the second row and below

Comment: Copy the file from the URL and put it in the question. Not recommended to post blind URLs

Comment: ... and tell us what you have done so far to solve this problem of yours

Comment: That's what I did, check out those tables in grey background, I provided the URL just so that it would be easy for people to try to help me.

Comment: Where do the new data for the two columns come from?

Comment: @Joe, what should be the logic of new data? Please mention that too.

Comment: It's random data, you can put whatever data you want, I just want to know how to replace it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following `awk` command and redirect the output to a new file:

```
$ awk -v var="OhYeah123" -v var2="xxxaaaasssss" 'NR>1{$2=var substr($3,length($3)-1,length($3)); $3=var2 (NR-1); print}NR==1' file.in          
time        my_account  form_token          address         City
13:19:43 OhYeah12345 xxxaaaasssss1 Street name 1 City 1
13:19:43 OhYeah12346 xxxaaaasssss2 Street name 2 City 2
13:19:43 OhYeah12347 xxxaaaasssss3 Street name 3 City 3
13:19:43 OhYeah12348 xxxaaaasssss4 Street name 4 City 4
```

I have defined 2 variables that you can use within `awk` to replace the fields by whatever you want.

- `NR==1` will print the first line
- `NR>1{$2=var substr($3,length($3)-1,length($3)); $3=var2 (NR-1); print}` from the 2nd line you replace the 2nd field and the 3rd field by the variable content and you concatenate it with the respectively `substr($3,length($3)-1,length($3)` and `(NR-1)` in order to have your output

If you do not need this logic, just use:

```
$ awk -v var="OhYeah123" -v var2="xxxaaaasssss" 'NR>1{$2=var; $3=var2;}1' file.in
```

Comment: Thanks but can you correct this command of mine, it starts replacing on the first row instead of the second one `awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '$1 {$3="Another Street"; print}' /tmp/demo.csv` I want to use this command if possible but it should start replacing from the second row instead

Comment: @Joe: try this command `awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' 'NR>1{$3="Another Street"; print}NR==1'`

Comment: or `awk -v var="OhYeah123" -v var2="xxxaaaasssss" 'NR>1 {$2=var; $3=var2}1' file`

Comment: @Cyrus: yes if he doesn't need any logic and would just like to replace the 2 fields ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Alan this command is what I've  been looking for: `awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' 'NR>1{$2="notusername1"; $3="Another Street"; print}NR==1' /tmp/demo.csv`

Comment: is there an option for `awk` to just save a modified file, just like how it's done with `sed -i` option ?

Comment: I'll accept your answer as soon as that last question is answered :D

Comment: SOLVED: HERE'S THE FINAL COMMAND `gawk -i inplace -F ',' -v OFS=',' 'NR>1{$2="notusername1"; $3="Another Street"; print}NR==1' /tmp/demo.csv`